# Fotorama images not centered

Tags: html, css, slideshow, fotorama

I am using Fotorama to create a slideshow however all of my images will not center. For example this is what it shows http://damien-harrow-photography.co.uk/picture.php?/285/category/2 . Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code to fotorama.css:

```
.fotorama__wrap {
margin: 0 auto; }
```